# call function and send parameter with composition API vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I´m trying call function from other component.

My parent component formTelemarketing() when i clicked in my button, should send data to my other component nAsignedCalls() and call function in this component getCalls(param) and this function call to function composable

```
const getCall = async (param_search) => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/callApi', {param_search: {'param_search': param_search} }) 
        console.log(response.data.data)
        calls.value = response.data.data
    }
```

But my problem it´s that i don´t know how i can call this function. i have this in my parent:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="Buscar registros" @click="searchRegisters()">

const nAsignedCalls = ref(null);
function searchRegisters(){
                var address = "";
                var city = "";
                var cp = "";

                address = document.getElementById("address").value
                if( address != "" ) {
                    param_search = "address";
                }

                city = document.getElementById("city").value
                if( city != "" ) {
                    param_search = "city";
                }

                cp = document.getElementById("postal_code").value
                if( cp != "" ) {
                    param_search = "cp";
                }

                nAsignedCalls.getCalls(param_search);
            }
```

and in my destiny component:

```
return {
   ...
   getCalls
}
```

but when cliked my button, return in console:

```
nAsignedCalls.getCalls is not a function
    at Proxy.searchRegisters (app.js:20068:21)
    at onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (app.js:21727:19)
    at callWithErrorHandling (app.js:7336:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (app.js:7345:21)
    at HTMLInputElement.invoker (app.js:15616:86)
```

update:

My composable:

```
export default function useNcalls(){
    let calls = ref([])
    let param_search = ref([])
    let pagination = ref([])

    const getCall = async (param_search) => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/callApi', {param_search: {'param_search': param_search} }) 
        console.log(response.data.data)
        calls.value = response.data.data
    } 
    const deleteCall = (id) => axios.post(`/api/callApi/${id}`, {_method: 'delete'}).then(res => {
        confirm("¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar el registro?") 
        location.reload();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });  
    
    const queryForKeywords = async (event) => {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/callApi/show', { params: { 'searchParams': event } }) 
        calls.value = response.data.data
    };

    const getResults = async (page) => {
        const response = axios.get('api/callApi?page=' + page)
        calls.value = response.data
    };

    const getItems = async (page) => {
        axios.get('/api/callApi?page='+page)
            .then(response => {
                calls.value = response.data.data;
                pagination.value = response.data.meta;
            });
    };

    expose({ getCalls })

    return{
        calls,
        getCall,
        deleteCall,
        queryForKeywords,
        getResults,
        getItems
    } 
}
```

what i´m doing wrong? thanks for read me and sorry for my bad english

Comment: There's no `getCalls` and no `expose` in useNcalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` from a setup() function only exposes a component's properties to its own template.  To expose properties to a parent component you have to use the [`expose` function](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#exposing-public-properties)

```js
export default {
  setup(props, { expose }) {
    const getCalls = () => { ... }

    expose({ getCalls })
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but return expor not defined, and my composobla not have setup() it´s a functio. Update my question with this

Comment: i understand your response, but expose() should be called only once per setup(). i need call this function in action button

Comment: If the function is from a composable then why do you have the line `const nAsignedCalls = ref(null);`?  `nAsignedCalls` should be imported.  See the [documentation regarding composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#mouse-tracker-example)

Comment: this line it´s removed y updated my question with all my composable and expose and now i can show my console.log() but expose() should be called only once per setup()

Comment: right, you dont expose from a composable, that advice was when I thought you were trying to expose the property of a child component.  with a composable you just export/import

Comment: any idea that how i can call to my function composable in my function searchRegisters that this function it´s in my component

Comment: Check the [documentation example](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#mouse-tracker-example), it's very close to your use case.  After you import your composable (useNcalls) you then use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to retrieve the other functions/properties from the composable (e.g. getCall) which makes them usable anywhere in your component